# Declarative Roll up Summary - How does it work when filter criteria changes

Tags: cpq, roll-up-summary, dlrs

I am using the declarative roll up summary tool to create a lookup on Account object to sum over all net prices of Subscriptions using a filter criteria as Active Contract = 1(1,0).

```
Parent Object : Account
Child Object : SBQQ_Subscriptions(Lookup to Account)
Aggregation Field : NetPrice
Aggregation Factor : Sum
```

I was able to implement using the tool and it works great. It also re-calculated for existing Accounts in the sandbox

**Question:**

1. What happens when for one of the Accounts the Contract becomes inactive? in that case the Sum field needs to be re-calculated for the account? Will this happen automatically or do we have to schedule this job end of day daily for re-calculation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So

If using DLRS in real-time mode, it requires a DML event on the child object (`SBQQ_Subscriptions`)  to cause any recalculation to occur. Under the covers, real-time DLRS is simply a trigger

If using DLRS in scheduled mode, then it will recalculate by running a batch job across all children

[Details about scheduled mode](https://github.com/SFDO-Community/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries/wiki/What-you-need-to-know-about-Scheduling-Rollups) (which can be used with realtime)

Comment: Can we do both batch and real time run?. Scenario is when subscription changes then real time trigger will take care and when lets say a contract expires the batch will reset the aggregated field?

Comment: I edited my answer

Comment: i dont think batch and real time is possible  The third option is it creates a async job for which you need to schedule another class